# Two-column card layout with every other row a double-width card using css-grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to prototype (using css-grid) a layout that contains cards in the main content well.

The cards are 50% wide, but I want to have it so that every third card is 100% wide so that the rows will alternate betweeen: 2 cards - 1 card- 2 cards - etc....

Is this even possible using css-grid only? I don't want to have to have a class on every 3rd one.

I was thinking of using :nth-child(3n+3), but the card width isn't determined on the card.  It's set up on the card-container using columns.

```
        @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@     @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
        @                           @     @                           @
        @                           @     @                           @
        @                           @     @                           @
        @                           @     @                           @
        @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@     @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

        @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
        @                                                             @
        @                                                             @
        @                                                             @
        @                                                             @
        @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

        @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@     @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
        @                           @     @                           @
        @                           @     @                           @
        @                           @     @                           @
        @                           @     @                           @
        @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@     @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

Here's the working prototype (but to see the layout above, you're going to have to click to [View on JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scott_in_ct/27ataodg/13/) as this content well is too narrow):

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}

.outer-wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 50px;
  grid-template-areas: "h h h h h h h h h h h h" "m m c c c c c c c c c c" "f f f f f f f f f f f f";
}

.header {
  grid-area: h;
  background-color: #ff00ff;
}

.menu {
  grid-area: m;
  background-color: #8800ff;
}

.content {
  grid-area: c;
  background-color: #0088ff;
}

.card-container {
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.card {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: none;
}

.card-container>div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: f;
  background-color: #888888;
}

.image {
  background: yellow;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-areas: "m h h h h h h h h h h h" "c c c c c c c c c c c c" "f f f f f f f f f f f f";
  }
  .card {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .card>*:last-child {
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-areas: "h h h h h h h h h h h m" "c c c c c c c c c c c c" "f f f f f f f f f f f f";
  }
  .card-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  h2 {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="menu">MENU</div>
    <div class="content">
      <h1> Content Well</h1>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="image">IMAGE</div>
          <div>
            <h2>Content Card</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="image">IMAGE</div>
          <div>
            <h2>Content Card</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Asperiores autem deleniti non quae quibusdam quidem rerum veritatis!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="image">IMAGE</div>
          <div>
            <h2>Content Card</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum in non quae quibusdam quidem rerum veritatis!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="image">IMAGE</div>
          <div>
            <h2>Content Card</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores autem deleniti eligendi illum in non quae quibusdam quidem rerum veritatis!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="image">IMAGE</div>
          <div>
            <h2>Content Card</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores autem deleniti eligendi illum in non quae quibusdam quidem rerum veritatis!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scott_in_ct/27ataodg/13/)

Comment: if Grid is not a hard requirement, you could do this with flexbox: https://jsfiddle.net/27ataodg/15/

Comment: Ohh, interesting.  That's cool.  If I remove the border, i can make that flex arg 50%.

Comment: @Scott Its done, you can see the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/07x2tcyx/

You need to change a few simple things to make it look like the layout you desire:

- For, .card  you need to define all the **3n cards** i.e 3,6,9..(we'll stretch it from 1-3 that is, it occupies 2 column space):

  ```
  .card:nth-child(3n){ grid-column: 1 / 3; }
  ```

And for the media query with max-width < 768px add this:

```
.card:nth-child(3n){ grid-column: 1 / 2; }
```

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}

.outer-wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 50px;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "h h h h h h h h h h h h" 
    "m m c c c c c c c c c c" 
    "f f f f f f f f f f f f";
}

.header {
  grid-area: h;
  background-color: #ff00ff;
}

.menu {
  grid-area: m;
  background-color: #8800ff;
}

.content {
  grid-area: c;
  background-color: #0088ff;
}

.card-container {
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.card {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: none;
}

.card:nth-child(3n){ grid-column: 1 / 3; }

.card-container > div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: f;
  background-color: #888888;
}

.image {
  background: yellow;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-areas: 
    "m h h h h h h h h h h h" 
    "c c c c c c c c c c c c" 
    "f f f f f f f f f f f f";
  }
  .card {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .card > *:last-child{
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-areas: 
    "h h h h h h h h h h h m" 
    "c c c c c c c c c c c c" 
    "f f f f f f f f f f f f";
  }
  .card:nth-child(3n){ grid-column: 1 / 2; }
  .card-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  h2 {text-align: center;}
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="menu">MENU</div>
    <div class="content">
      <h1> Content Well</h1>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="image">IMAGE</div>
          <div>
            <h2>Content Card</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="image">IMAGE</div>
          <div>
            <h2>Content Card</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Asperiores autem deleniti non quae quibusdam quidem rerum veritatis!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="image">IMAGE</div>
          <div>
            <h2>Content Card</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum in non quae quibusdam quidem rerum veritatis!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="image">IMAGE</div>
          <div>
            <h2>Content Card</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores autem deleniti eligendi illum in non quae quibusdam quidem rerum veritatis!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="image">IMAGE</div>
          <div>
            <h2>Content Card</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores autem deleniti eligendi illum in non quae quibusdam quidem rerum veritatis!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes!  Thanks.  I just needed another layer in the card!  working fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/scott_in_ct/27ataodg/ with the content cards ALL THE SAME MARKUP.

Comment: @Scott No problem :)